# Twitter most followers

Tags: php, jquery, twitter

Using Jquery or PHP is it possible to get a list from twitter API or similar of the top 100 people with most followers?

How can I do this?

Comment: A cursory glace at the [documentation](http://dev.twitter.com/doc) says, no this isn't possible. Their API exposes user feeds and general searches.

Comment: I see.  There is a website that does this, any ideas how they do it then?

Comment: My guess is they scrape the Twitter site heavily.

Comment: yeah..they save the details in their db and then calculate most followed users etc..